# CoolProp module does not take 3 arguments

Tags: python

This is my module

```
def enthalpy_Q_P(q,p,f):
    h1=cp.PropsSI('H','Q',q,'P',p,f)
    return h1
```

But when I call it in this style

```
def thermo_problem(p1,p2,t3):
    f= raw_input("Enter the Fluid:")
    import props
    import numpy as np    
    h1=props.enthalpy_Q_P(0,p1,f1)
```

It shows this as error

```
thermo_problem(75e3,3e6,623)

Enter the Fluid:water

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-84-6060bb46d899>", line 1, in <module>
    thermo_problem(75e3,3e6,623)

  File "<ipython-input-83-c72b065e1660>", line 8, in thermo_problem
    h1=props.enthalpy_Q_P(0,p1,f1) 

TypeError: enthalpy_Q_P() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Comment: You should move those imports out of the function and to the top of the file.

Comment: Do you have another function also named `enthalpy_Q_P` ?

Comment: no I don't have any .

Comment: @BadrulHasanTanjil Is thermo_problem method in class? Because in this case you should see the answer of TimmSimpkins in other case you should put more details of your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is in a class, you have to use self as your first argument.

```
def enthalpy_Q_P(self,q,p,f):
    h1=cp.PropsSI('H','Q',q,'P',p,f)
    return h1
```